# Why does Rolle get its own theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

The importance of Rolle's theorem lies in the fact that it's used to prove the mean value theorem, which is a central result of analysis, eventually leading to the fundamental theorem of calculus. But if I compare the usual proof of the mean value theorem to other typical proofs, I come to the conclusion that the theory is built up differently than usual. A typical proof in analysis might start off with: "Without loss of generality, assume $f(0)=0$, otherwise consider $f(x)-f(0)$", or similar statements. The mean value theorem could go exactly the same way: "without loss of generality, assume $f(a)=f(b)$, otherwise consider $f(x)-(x-a)\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$", and then we'd just use the proof of Rolle's theorem.

But in the "canonical" development of analysis, Rolle's theorem gets to be its own theorem, instead of just being part of the proof of the mean value theorem. Why is that? Does it have any other significant applications I'm unaware of? For instance, the special case of the identity theorem in complex analysis which says that zeros of holomorphic functions $\neq0$ are isolated is important on its own because it's used in treating isolated singularities of fractions of holomorphic functions. This makes it a reasonable thing to declare as a theorem of its own, even though it could also be a lemma on the way to the identity theorem. I don't know of any such important application of Rolle's theorem. Or is it a pedagogical choice, aiming to make the structure of the argument for the MVT clearer? Any other possible, maybe historical reasons?

Comment: [A brief history of the mean value theorem (2012)](https://abesenyei.web.elte.hu/publications/meanvalue.pdf)

Comment: Craig Smorynski, [MVT: A Most Valuable Theorem (Springer, 2017)](https://books.google.it/books?id=lnuhDgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: To me it seems like just a pedagogical choice.

Comment: I agree with @littleO ... Beginning calculus courses have many students who never wrote proofs before.  Therefore, we take the few proofs to be done, and divide them into small steps.  Singling out something and calling it "Rolle's Theorem" is a pedagogical choice to help students see the structure of the proof.

Comment: It is called also * Rolle's lemma*, indeed. Rolle lived *before* the  MVT (1690) see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Rolle#Work. Trivia: Rolle was one of the few "anti calculus" mathematicians :)

Comment: @Infinity_hunter Depends on what the answer is. If the reasons are mostly historical, then yes. If they're mostly pedagogical, then it would rather belong into the math educator stack exchange. And if the reasons were more structural, then it would belong here. I wasn't sure what kind of answers to expect, so I thought that it was best to ask here.